# Template functions with STL Vectors break with new allocator

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

I have a ton of functions that are defined as something like:

```
template<typename T>
void myFunction1(vector<T>& vin);
```

The point being, I input an STL vector and do some work.

I have recently needed to change the default allocator to a customer allocator. This seems to break every function unless I change the definitions to:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc>
void myFunction1(vector<T,Alloc>& vin);
```

To make it more complicated, I will not be using the overloaded allocator in all cases..

Does this mean I have to rewrite EVERY function with two definitions, one with the template for the allocator and the other definition without the allocator? I really hope this isn't the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely adequate to have one single function template that respects the full class template. Hypothetically, this will do:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
void myFunction1(std::vector<T, Alloc> & v);
```

*Every* vector has those two arguments, no matter whether the allocator one is defaulted or not.

However, a more fruitful idiom is actually to make the entire container a template:

```
template <typename V>
void myFunction1(V & v)
{
    typedef typename V::value_type value_type;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to go to variadics. The library requirements say that there's a template named `vector` that takes two type arguments; while implementations are allowed to add extra arguments, they aren't allowed to make `vector<Type, Allocator>` not work. The place where you can run into trouble is if you try to write your own declaration of a standard library type. Using a standard library type is simply required to work as documented.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You're right. I was thinking of a different situation (specialization) where the "allowed extra arguments" come to bite you. Let me remove it from this post, though!

Comment: @PeteBecker: If you're curious, that's currently an open issue in the [pretty printer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers): I want to provide specialized delimiters for sets, but I don't have a portable solution.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution could be to implement your functions in terms of iterators, as is done in standard library algorithms:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void myFunction1(Iterator1 first, Iterator2 last) { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too change your template.
But the good news is you can change your template to this:

```
template <typename MyVector> 
void myFunction1(MyVector& vin);
```

Comment: Of course, that change means that the function can be called with any type at all, not just a `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide two overloads for each function template. Just provide the two-parameter one. `std::vector` has two template parameters, so both will be deduced just fine.